# How to get while loop to work?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having trouble getting the while loop to work the way I want it. I've written a method called trapezium (that calculates the area of a trapezium). I need the screen to print the area of the trapezium, then the area of a trapezium with the value of N doubled and then the difference between these two, which it does.

I then need the while loop to keep doubling N, inputting this in the formula, and printing the new difference UNTIL this new difference is less than or equal to a user inputted value called eps. It then needs to print to the screen the area found and the value of N required to do this.

```
double traparea = trapezium(a, b, N);

System.out.println(traparea + " using the trapezium rule");
double traparea2 = trapezium(a, b, 2 * N);
double difftrap = (traparea2 - traparea);

System.out.println(traparea2);
System.out.println(difftrap);


while (Math.abs(difftrap) < eps) {
    N = 2 * N;
    traparea2 = trapezium(a, b, N);
    difftrap = traparea2 - traparea;
}

System.out.println("The integration from trapezium rule and the value of N are:");
System.out.print(traparea2 + " " + N);
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

UNTIL this new difference is less than or equal to a user inputted value called eps

while (difftrap>eps)  // do the loop as long as the difference is not less than or equal to eps

Comment: The problem is the last line prints the value of traparea2 found at the beginning as well as the original value entered for N. It seems to me that the loop is being ignored entirely no matter if its < or >